# Kadelmia Join operation: what does "refresh" mean in the context of join opreation?

Tags: dht

The paper says:

> To join the network, a node u must have a contact to an already
> participating node w. u inserts w into the appropriate k-bucket. u
> then performs a node lookup for its own node ID. Finally, u refreshes
> all kbuckets further away than its closest neighbor. **During the
> refreshes, u both populates its own k-buckets and inserts itself into
> other nodes’ k-buckets as necessary**

The definition of the refresh is the following:

> Refreshing means picking a random ID in the bucket’s range and
> performing a node search for that ID.

I don't understand the last part. Per my understanding, in the intermediate steps of the node lookup operation, the neighbors of the node u will have stored node u inside their own k-buckets. At the end, node u will store its k neighbors inside the appropriate k-buckets. (as shown in the visualization [here](https://kelseyc18.github.io/kademlia_vis/join/))

So I don't understand what value is being gained from performing a refresh *after* doing the lookup.

A walkthrough example with simple parameters would super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A lookup targeting the node's own ID is not guaranteed to visit enough other nodes to fill all buckets. So after performing a lookup that fills the home bucket additional refreshes targeting the other buckets are performed to completely fill them.